# How to test stripe Standard connect integration since test accounts need validation first?

Tags: testing, stripe-payments

When trying via code to create standard accounts, the option to skip the form is not present. Even though the page to connect the account shows the test-mode tag, the page expects you to fill the form with "real" data.

When creating the account using the Stripe Dashboard in test mode, you are given a link that shows the New account flow and it has a "skip form" option. The option basically closes the form, but the account is still in restricted mode.

[image: standard accounts with skip-form are initially restricted and there is no way to provide test data so that their status changes]

What is required to have a Standard test account in order to test the other functionality of charges, checkouts, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test mode, even if the Standard account is restricted, you should be able to use all Stripe features. And if you want to change the status of the account from "restricted" to "completed", then you have to provide all the information listed in the screenshot you shared.

Note that the recommended way to connect Standard accounts to your platform is to use [Connect onboarding](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts).

Comment: I could create customers, and capture their payment details.
The thing is not possible to do is start checkout sessions even for one of those newly created customers.

Comment: It should be possible to create Checkout Sessions with a restricted standard account in test mode. What error are you getting?

Comment: The issue is that the account is missing details like the name.

For example, trying to change the account.business_profile.name returns the following.

`Stripe::AuthenticationError ((Status 401) This application does not have the required permissions for the parameter 'business_profile' on account 'acct_1X'.)`

My user has connected accounts analyst role.

When trying to start the StripeCheckout.js I get this error on the browser console:

`{"message":"In order to use Checkout, you must set an account or business name at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account."}`

Comment: One option is to login directly in the Standard Connected account to update the business name in the [dashboard here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account). And then you will be able to create Checkout Sessions.

Comment: Silly me, I had not considered that!
Just by adding the company name I was able to create checkout payment flows.